# Modify existing keyword code to include multiple searches

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

The code below finds a keyword in a document, copies the sentence where keyword is found, and places it into an excel document.

I wanted to know if this code could be modify to search for multiple keywords at the same time, and place each keyword in a separate column (or sheet) within the same spreadsheet.

So, for example, if I searched 5 keywords at the same time, it would put keyword 1 output on column 1, keyword 2 output on column 2, keyword 3 output on column 3, and so on.

```
Sub FindWordCopySentence()
    Dim appExcel As Object
    Dim objSheet As Object
    Dim aRange As Range
    Dim intRowCount As Integer
    intRowCount = 1
    Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    With aRange.Find
        Do
            .Text = "Hair"
            .Execute
            If .Found Then
                aRange.Expand Unit:=wdSentence
                myTempText = aRange.Text
                aRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                If objSheet Is Nothing Then
                    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                                         Set objSheet = appExcel.workbooks.Open("C:\Users\HNR\Desktop\hair.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
                    intRowCount = 1
                End If
                objSheet.Cells(intRowCount, 1).Value = myTempText
                intRowCount = intRowCount + 1
            End If
        Loop While .Found
    End With
    If Not objSheet Is Nothing Then
        appExcel.workbooks(1).Close True
        appExcel.Quit
        Set objSheet = Nothing
        Set appExcel = Nothing
    End If
    Set aRange = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You can place the bulk of your code inside a loop that iterates over all the values you want to search for:

```
Sub FindWordCopySentence()
    Dim appExcel As Object
    Dim objSheet As Object
    Dim aRange As Range
    Dim intRowCount As Integer
    Dim myTempText As String
    Dim findObjects() As Variant
    Dim findIndex As Integer
    'Create array of items to search for
    findObjects = Array("Hair", "something", "else", "to", "search", "for")
    'Loop across each item in the array
    For findIndex = LBound(findObjects) To UBound(findObjects)
        intRowCount = 1
        Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Range
        With aRange.Find
            Do
                'Search for current search term
                .Text = findObjects(findIndex)
                .Execute
                If .Found Then
                    aRange.Expand Unit:=wdSentence
                    myTempText = aRange.Text
                    aRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                    If objSheet Is Nothing Then
                        Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                        Set objSheet = appExcel.workbooks.Open("C:\Users\HNR\Desktop\hair.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
                        intRowCount = 1
                    End If
                    'Write output to column based on which position of array we are processing
                    objSheet.Cells(intRowCount, findIndex + 1 - LBound(findObjects)).Value = myTempText
                    intRowCount = intRowCount + 1
                End If
            Loop While .Found
        End With
    Next
    If Not objSheet Is Nothing Then
        appExcel.workbooks(1).Close True
        appExcel.Quit
        Set objSheet = Nothing
        Set appExcel = Nothing
    End If
    Set aRange = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I tried your suggestion and it worked perfectly. You're amazing!